# Open A Different TaskPane via Current Taskpane - Office-JS

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I have two taskpanes that I can open via clicking each button in the UI/Ribbon.

What I'm trying to do is have one button that opens a taskpane and a button in that taskpane that opens up the second taskpane. So far, I can only redirect the current taskpane. Can I somehow open the second taskpane from the first via JS?

This is in Excel.

Comment: Just FYI, I ended up designing what I think is an `SPA` Single Page Applicaiton. In essence, I have on HTML Taskpane that has nothing really loaded and an empty `div` that I use `jquery` to load individual TaskPanes that are basically stripped of the outer html and it works great. Allows not having to re-load the page for one and enables session storage to work across "taskpanes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't literally do that. You can open a [dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/design/dialog-boxes) from a task pane, but not another task pane. Does your use case require both task panes to be open at the same time? If not, consider creating a tabbed experience inside the task pane; so there's one task pane, but two tabs.

Comment: Will you allow that in the future?

Comment: @yossico There are no plans for that, and it's highly questionable whether it would be a good add-in design anyway. Each task pane is an entire embedded web control with its own session with the server. The server thinks it is two different clients. This makes sharing data and authorization across more than one task pane difficult, although not impossible.

Comment: I have multiple Taskpanes w/ multiple tabs already, but I prefer using buttons in the taskpane to direct users "deeper" to the Taskpane they are really after. Its a few more clicks then my VBA/XLAM which had tons of buttons in the ribbon, but I got feedback from users that too many buttons in ribbon was confusing. My workaround for "power users" is keyboard shortcuts. I posted my solution up to @yossico